# How to make a service like the Android System Services?

Tags: android, android-service-binding, system-services

I'm working on what Android calls [software-based sensors](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview.html). Logically, I cannot put my algorithms directly in the Android's MotionManager. These algorithms can be used for different applications. Some specific parameters can be set by any application and affect the behavior of all others. The output from algorithms is something like a `float[4]` at 100Hz.

I'm looking for a good design pattern but I'm not sure if this is possible with Android because:

- I cannot directly add my code to Android's MotionManager (obviously)
- A basic library imported in all apps is not designed for this purpose.
- "Bind" side of [Bind Services](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) is interesting, but, I think they are not designed to work with multiple applications. Moreover, the code for binding is not easier than: [`registerListener (SensorEventListener listener, Sensor sensor, int samplingPeriodUs)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#registerListener(android.hardware.SensorEventListener, android.hardware.Sensor, int)) for the developer.
- [AIDL](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html) can handle the "multiple app" side of the service but I don't feel like it is the way to do it for the same reason than the bind service (passing references).

Comment: if you need IPC the "natural way" is either `AIDL` or `android.os.Messenger`, alternatively you can create a "pipe" and pass it to the other app for reading / writing

Comment: The options you have are 1) as per @pskink commented or 2) customizing AOSP.

Answer (score 2):

Did you take a look at http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Android-Adding_SystemService ?

Writing a small a library to hide the stubs and to handle exceptions might allow you to share the service across applications with a simple API.

Comment: The solution in the link provided requires building a custom ROM.

Comment: Indeed, but I don't think it is possible to add a new system service without building a custom ROM.